# Logout takes too long: how to find the reason?

Tags: unity, logout

Logging out the session (**not** on shutdown) takes too long: more than 3 minutes on my netbook. On the process CPU isn't working, seems just waiting. No difference using indicator menu, shortcut key, or the command `gnome-session-quit --logout`.

- On first half of the period some apps, e.g. Tomboy Notes, are closed. Everything else keep working: indicators, Launcher, Dash, shortcuts,….
- On the second half everything is disappeared except the wallpaper.

**How can I find out the reason for the problem? Are there any special logs for logout process?**

Comment: I also have the same problem, especially after I installed XFCE environment. There's no problem when I log out from XFCE session, but Logging out from unity takes times and for sometime, the system looks like doing nothing after I log out. *Sorry I have to post this on the answer session, I'm a newbie user. My reputation's not enough to just comment.

Comment: Did you eventually find a culprit or did you just give up?

Comment: @guntbert, it seems the reason is conflicts between settings of different DEs. I tried to find settings related to Cinnamon (which I had on the same home folder) and delete them. Now I get more successful logouts, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Strange, I was not aware of having toyed with different DEs at all, but I experience a significant logout delay very similar to the one you described - but not every time. In another post I found a pointer to `/var/log/lightdm/`, maybe that will shed some light on this issue :-))